# Filter array of objects based on content of another array of nested objects

Tags: javascript, lodash

I want to filter the `positions` array and remove any positions that are represented in the `people` array.

I've tried a few combinations of `_.forEach` and `_.filter` but just can't seem to figure it out.

```
console.log(position)

var test = _.filter(position, function(pos) {
    _.forEach(people, function(peo) {
        _.forEach(peo.position, function(peoplePos) {
            if(peoplePos.value == pos.value){
                return false;
            }
        });
    });
});

console.log(test)
```

My main problem, I think, is the positions are nested inside each people object

```
var positions = [{
    val: 'CEO',
    label: 'CEO XXX'
}, {
    val: 'CTO',
    label: 'CTO XXX'
}, {
    val: 'CBO',
    label: 'CBO XXX'
}, {
    val: 'CLO',
    label: 'CLO XXX'
}]

var people = [{
    id: 'AAA',
    positions: [{
        val: 'CEO',
        label: 'CEO XXX'
    }]
},{
    id: 'BBB',
    positions: [{
        val: 'CXO',
        label: 'CXO XXX'
    },{
        val: 'CEO',
        label: 'CEO XXX'
    }]
},{
    id: 'CCC',
    positions: [{
        val: 'CTO',
        label: 'CTO XXX'
    }]
}]
```

In this scenario, I'm aiming for the following outcome:

```
var positions = [{
    val: 'CBO',
    label: 'CBO XXX'
}, {
    val: 'CLO',
    label: 'CLO XXX'
}]
```

As CBO and CLO are not represented by any object in the people array.

Comment: For a user with your rep, you should know the importance of sharing effort

Comment: @Rajesh yep, sorry about that. One minute

Comment: `.map()` the persons array to extract all positions arrays, then flatMap ( or flatten then map ) the result so you have an array containing all the positions currently occupied by at least one person. Then just `.filter()` the positions array using `occupied_positions.includes( position )`.

Comment: @Rajesh question updated. Just had to ctrl + z back far enough to a point where it sort of made sense

Comment: @Daft Pointer 1, you have 2 forEach but you are not returning from the outer forEach

Comment: `positions` is not `position`, and `value` is not `val`. A `filter` callback needs a `return` to do anything useful, and `_.forEach` just returns the original collection. Did you check the console when running this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick way is to stringify both the people array and check for position in the string.

This saves you the trouble of looping through a nested structure.

```js
var positions = [{ val: 'CEO', label: 'CEO XXX' }, { val: 'CTO', label: 'CTO XXX' }, { val: 'CBO', label: 'CBO XXX' }, { val: 'CLO', label: 'CLO XXX' }]

var people = [{ id: 'AAA', positions: [{ val: 'CEO', label: 'CEO XXX' }] }, { id: 'BBB', positions: [{ val: 'CXO', label: 'CXO XXX' }, { val: 'CEO',
    label: 'CEO XXX' }] }, { id: 'CCC', positions: [{ val: 'CTO', label: 'CTO XXX' }] }];

var stringifiedPeople = JSON.stringify(people)

var newPositions = positions.filter((position) =>
  !stringifiedPeople.includes(JSON.stringify(position))
);

console.log(newPositions)
```

Or you can create a map that holds all occupied positions and filter out positions that are available.

```js
var positions = [{ val: 'CEO', label: 'CEO XXX' }, { val: 'CTO', label: 'CTO XXX' }, { val: 'CBO', label: 'CBO XXX' }, { val: 'CLO', label: 'CLO XXX' }]

var people = [{ id: 'AAA', positions: [{ val: 'CEO', label: 'CEO XXX' }] }, { id: 'BBB', positions: [{ val: 'CXO', label: 'CXO XXX' }, { val: 'CEO',
    label: 'CEO XXX' }] }, { id: 'CCC', positions: [{ val: 'CTO', label: 'CTO XXX' }] }];

var mappedPositions = {}

people.forEach((p) =>
  p.positions.forEach((position) =>
    mappedPositions[position.val] = true
  )
);

var newPositions = positions.filter((position) => !mappedPositions[position.val]);

console.log(newPositions)
```

Comment: The mapping solution is great, really appreciate the assistance. Tried something similar but it didn't pan out. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter), [`find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find), and [`some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) to filter out those objects that don't appear in the positions array of the people array.

```js
var positions = [{val:'CEO',label:'CEOXXX'},{val:'CTO',label:'CTOXXX'},{val:'CBO',label:'CBOXXX'},{val:'CLO',label:'CLOXXX'}];
var people = [{id:'AAA',positions:[{val:'CEO',label:'CEOXXX'}]},{id:'BBB',positions:[{val:'CXO',label:'CXOXXX'},{val:'CEO',label:'CEOXXX'}]},{id:'CCC',positions:[{val:'CTO',label:'CTOXXX'}]}];

const out = positions.filter(position => {
  return !people.find(person => {
    return person.positions.some(({ val, label }) => {
      return val === position.val && label === position.label;
    });
  });
});

console.log(out);
```

Answer (score 1):

Implementation of my comment.

The whole thing can be written as a big `.reduce()` on the positions array to make it more efficient, but I preferred showing the exact steps to make it more clear what each step does.

```js
var positions = [{val:'CEO',label:'CEOXXX'},{val:'CTO',label:'CTOXXX'},{val:'CBO',label:'CBOXXX'},{val:'CLO',label:'CLOXXX'}];

var people = [{id:'AAA',positions:[{val:'CEO',label:'CEOXXX'}]},{id:'BBB',positions:[{val:'CXO',label:'CXOXXX'},{val:'CEO',label:'CEOXXX'}]},{id:'CCC',positions:[{val:'CTO',label:'CTOXXX'}]}];

const occupied_positions = people
  .map( person => person.positions )
  .flat()
  .map( position => position.val );
  
const all_positions = positions
  .map( position => position.val );
  
const open_positions = all_positions
  .filter( position => !occupied_positions.includes( position ))
  .map( position => positions.find( source => source.val === position ));
  
console.log( open_positions );
```

Comment: Just a pointer, you should use minified version of data. That keeps focus on your code. You can copy it from my or Andy's answer.

Comment: I used [this tool](https://www.browserling.com/tools/remove-all-whitespace) because I'm lazy.

Comment: Good point. :) Becuase I do not have a horizontal scrolling wheel, I wrongly assumed people hated scrolling to the right to be able to read inputs as much as I do.